# How use same context on child routes in react-router v3?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I need to use the same context over different routes. This is possible in the latest versions of `react-router`, but how can I achieve the same in `react-router-v3`? Here, is the sample code:

```
{
    path: "/",
    getChildRoutes(_: LocationState, cb: RoutesCallback) {
        const routes = require("./routes").default;
        cb(null, routes());
    },
}
```

I need to add the same `ContextProvider` for all the child routes. Currently, I render a `Layout` component which is responsible to change the child components based on state value. The function is in the context. But I need to render these child components as independent routes and wrap all of them with the same context which I am not sure how can I achieve.